# How to check if json from network is converted to my object or not using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am getting network response correctly (I checked it using `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY`), but my viewModel LiveData is still empty.

```
projectMembers = Transformations.switchMap(selectedProjectId, input -> cuttingListRepository.getProjectMembersByProjectUnit(input));
```

In above code `projectMembers.getValue()` is still null

I see no error in console, It could be that my json response is not getting converted to object how to be sure about this?

I m observing it inside fragment's onCreateView --

```
cuttingComponentViewModel.projectMembers.observe(this.getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<PojoProjectMember>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<PojoProjectMember> pojoProjectMembers) {
            System.out.println("getting observed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you ask question put yourself in our place and think if the information you provided is sufficient.

Comment: i assume that i have provided information as per my question, i clearly mentioned that i am getting response which means switchmap is being triggered, then if i am getting response but not getting object what could be the problem other than that of object conversion.  I could be wrong thats why i was asking how can i get exception if my conversion is failed.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData will always be null, unless it is observed by something. 
Ensure you are observing the data from your activity / fragment.

Comment: That is why i already mentioned that i am getting response correctly, that means switch map is triggered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**change your ApiClient class for retrofit with this code in which gson convertor factory is used**

```
public static ApiInterface retrofit = null;

    public static ApiInterface getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if (retrofit == null) {

            Retrofit retro = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();

            retrofit = retro.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }

        return retrofit;
    }
```

**and serialize your pojo class like that**

```
public class ResponseModel {

    @SerializedName("success")
    public boolean success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

**In serialize name used api response keywords**

Comment: Is @serialize is necessary if I use field name same as response? I didn't use serialize in my model.

Comment: it is necessary for good performance and also for matching the key parameters, try with that it will solve your problem and don't forgot to use gson convertor factory like i  used in ApiClient.